# Why isn't font-style working for removing 'italic' style?

Tags: html, css

Here's my website: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/

I've tried to remove the italic font-style on the first element of my navigation bar and change it to `font-style: normal;`, but it does not seem to be working.

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
li#menu-item-15113 {
   text-transform: none;
   font-family: Caviar Dreams;
   font-style: normal !important;
}

#menu-item-15113 a {
   text-transform: none !important;
   font-family: Caviar Dreams !important;
   font-style: normal !important;
}
```

I am wondering what I should do to remove that italic style on the first menu-link? Any idea? You can inspect element right on my website if you want.

Comment: Hi .header-v4 #navigation > ul > li:first-child a{ font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-style: normal !important;}

Comment: did not work still

Comment: i can't see first menu http://www.iliveaccountable.com/  please check

Answer (score 1):

I ran your webpage through the CSS Validator ([check the results](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iliveaccountable.com%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)) and it seems like you're having several issues in there. Some of them you should just ignore, as the validator does not understand stuff like gardients for example.

Yet there seems to be some simple and quite critical issues, like missing `}` closures and so forth.

This might just be the reason your `font-style: normal` is not working, even with the `!important` which made me wonder if there is just some parse errors in the code. When the code breaks, it does not work properly any longer, if it does at all.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Cruch variant: using 
// change deg num for your font

```
#menu-item-15113 a {
transform: skewY(10deg) rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS-rule:

```
header-v4 #navigation > ul > li:first-child a { 
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;    
   font-style: normal !important;
}
```